# CakePHP routes always pointing to same action

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I am facing some problems in routing under cakephp

there are three actions in my controller

they are as below

```
www.example.com/photos/newphotos
www.example.com/photos/random
www.example.com/photos/popular
```

I want them as

```
www.example.com/newphotos
www.example.com/random
www.example.com/popular
```

so i routes file under config file I wrote as

```
Router::connect('/:newphotos', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'newphotos'));
Router::connect('/:popular', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'popular'));
Router::connect('/:random', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'random'));
```

its working fine when I hit the url 
www.example.com/newphotos

but when I hit url  www.example.com/random  or www.example.com/popular , its again point to action newphotos.

so how can I solve it

(In other words I need to remove controller name "photos" from url for every action)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove the `:` from the routes?

If you want to stick with `/:` paths, then you would need to supply a third parameter to `Router::connect()` in which to specify patterns for the added options. That is, if you have `/:popular` as the first parameter, you would need `array('popular' => 'popular')` as the third parameter, making the rule look like:

```
Router::connect('/:popular', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'popular'), array('popular' => 'popular'));
```

This means that `:popular` will be matched against the given regex, that is the literal 'popular'. See [CakePHP's docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) for more info.

Nevertheless, this is useless and silly, so you should stick with paths without colons.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the colon from the first parameter. They are kind of "capturing variables", so now you basically are routing all `/` with some parameters to `photos/newphotos`, and the parameters being captured to `:newphotos`. As it always will match the first route, then it will not look for the others.